# How to call class method at lodash debounce?

Tags: javascript

I have an error: **TypeError: Expected a function
at debounce** at calling class method in the lodash debounce

```js
class Foo {
  bar() {
    console.log('bar');
  }
}

const foo = new Foo();

_.debounce = debounce(foo.bar(), 300);
```

Comment: You are calling `bar()` and putting the return value of the `bar()` method as the first argument to `debounce()`, which is `undefined`, use `debounce(() => foo.bar(),  300)` to keep the correct `this` inside of `bar` (you're not currently using `this` inside of bar(), but it will help future-proof your code incase you decide to).

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is because when JavaScript looks at your code, it first **calls** the function `foo.bar()`, does whatever is inside it, and then **the return value of the function becomes the first parameter to the `debounce` function**. Since you didn't return anything, the first argument to the function became `undefined`, and obviously, `undefined` is not a function. This happens because you have used the parentheses () to actually invoke the function and **not** to pass it.

To fix this, you have to remove the parentheses. This will pass a **reference to the function** to the `debounce` method, and not actually invoke it. Then, the code inside denounce will call the method you've passed as a reference to it, and do it's work.